# connect to a wlan: Can't allocate interface wllease { interface Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

I've a wlan0 configured in my rasp pi (file /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf)
In the past I could connect to it with no problems but now I can't. I've tried a few different LANs and I can't get any to work.

Everytime I do either ifdown or ifup I get the result:

```
 Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
 Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
 All rights reserved.
 For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

 Can't allocate interface wllease {
   interface .
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but this happens when the dhcp lease file gets corrputed.

Try clearing the wlan0 leases with:

```
sudo echo "" > /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be just to remove the lease files using the following command.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp/*
```